# Loop through ID starting with speciific string

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

I need a pure JavaScript solution for following jQuery code:

```
$('[id^=name_]').each(function() {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: Look up `querySelectorAll`

Comment: @NisargShah, `querySelectorAll` returns an iterable `NodeList` and not an array and you'd use `NodeList.prototype.forEach` 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: @AshishJhanwar - For older browsers, `NodeLists` do not have the `forEach` method and you have to play around with `Array.prototype.forEach` or other silliness.  I think IE11 qualifies as an "older browser" in this context.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher,  then you add a polyfill (A sample is provided on the MDN page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `document.querySelectorAll()` and with `for` loop like follows:

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=name_]');

for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
    console.log(nodes[i].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="name_a">aaa</div>
<div id="name_b">bbb</div>
```

**Please note:** with `nodes.forEach` you will get an exeption

> "Uncaught TypeError: nodes.forEach is not a function"

because `nodes` is a `NodeList` and not an `Array`.

But if you want use `Array.forEach()` then you have to cast `NodeList` into `Array` like in following example:

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=name_]');

[].forEach.call(nodes, function(elm)
{
    console.log(elm.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div id="name_a">aaa</div>
<div id="name_b">bbb</div>
```

Please see documentation:

- [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` will get a `NodeList` of all the `Nodes` that match your selector, then you can do a forEach on it to access. The following is a JavaScript equivalent.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=name_]').forEach(n => { //do something here})
```